# Capacitor in an voltage doubler

Tags: rectifier, multiplier, charge-pump

In a standard diode voltage doubler (multiplier):

[image]
Does the capacitor also plays the role of smoothing out the output voltage?

Comment: The capacitor on the right does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rightmost capacitor does smoothen the output voltage. The left capacitor is used as a charge pump. It charges during one half cycle and discharges (to the right) during the second half cycle.

Notice though that the output impedance of such a circuit is very high and with a small load a noticable ripple will already occur.

[Wikipedia has a nice article on Voltage doublers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler)